# Ellipsize is not working

Tags: android, layout

I have a TextView which i set the text using setText(). In properties, I have set:

```
Ellipsize = END
Lines = 1
Gravity = Left
Scroll Horizontal = False
```

But this clips extra text (clips text since where last space is found). But do not include dots ("...") at the end.

Example:

```
-------------------------------
|                             |
 Hi how are you ? And where are you now ?
|                             |
|                             |
```

After clipping:

```
-------------------------------
|                             |
 Hi how are you ? And where 
|                             |
|                             |
```

What I want:

```
-------------------------------
|                             |
 Hi how are you ? And where...
|                             |
|                             |
```

I am using Android 1.6. Plz help.

Comment: can you paste the `XML`. Try using: `android:singleLine="true"`

Comment: but that is depreciated. Is it ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`android:singleLine="true"` and `textView.setEllipsize(TruncateAt.END);`

These are the two key elements to achieve that.

Comment: i donot understand. When i set SingleLine = TRUE, it works. But it is depreciated !!!

Comment: no it's not deprecated.. as the ellipsize works when our textview has single line enables or the max lines are set for that..

Comment: thanku. But still I donot know. In properties window this SingleLine is listed below "Depreceated" in my Eclipse !

Comment: you can also set the ellipsize in the xml: android:ellipsize="end"

Comment: @PratikButani The ellipsize works on 4.0 also.I tested it it's working

Comment: @ArpitGarg I have given

android:lines="1"
android:scrollHorizontally="true"
android:ellipsize="end"

then also not work for me.... how you have given??

Comment: @PratikButani The android:scrollHorizontally="true" is different aspect, it is intended to auto-scroll. The text auto scroll won't work in 4.0 and up. The question was just to have ellipse size(...) at end of text view not auto-scroll. Your requirement is different to the question and answer suggested.

Comment: @ArpitGarg Ya i have removed it then also it will not work for me.
Last char of string is displaying in second line if string is bigger than textview...

Comment: @PratikButani make sure to give android:singleLine="true" with width fill_parent , why is it going in next lines

Comment: Hey @ArpitGarg, Its working for me in Textview. Thanks. But now i want to do for Tab in TabActivity. Please Help me for that

Comment: instead of android:singelLine="true", you can use android:maxLines="1". that is not deprecated.

Answer (score 3):

```
        android:singleLine
```

is **deprecated**.

Here is what the documentation says:

"This attribute is deprecated and is replaced by the 
 textMultiLine flag in the inputType attribute. Use caution when 
 altering existing layouts, as the default value of singeLine is false 
 (multi-line mode), but if you specify any value for inputType, the 
 default is single-line mode. (If both singleLine and inputType 
 attributes are found, the inputType flags will override the value 
 of singleLine.). [boolean]"

To solve your problem.
You can use the following:

```
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
```

Answer (score 2):

`Textview` has a property call `singleLine` make it `true` in your XML file.

If you are doing through code then

```
textView.setSingleLine(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

here work for me

```
android:ellipsize="end"
android:singleLine="true"
```