# Android Ellipsize functionality not displayed correctly

Tags: android, android-layout

I have seen a few questions about the same problem, "Ellipsize is not working". None of the solutions work for me. Actually, the textview is setted like this:

As seen in [Ellipsize not working for textView inside custom listView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424276/ellipsize-not-working-for-textview-inside-custom-listview).

```
<com.neopixl.pixlui.components.textview.TextView
    android:id="@+id/wifispot_info_address"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="@string/default_string"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    pixlui:typeface="NeutraText-Book.otf"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:singleLine="true"/>
```

Also I tried to set the property in the fragment code, as seen here [Ellipsize is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9981655/ellipsize-is-not-working):

```
spotAddress = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.wifispot_info_address);
spotAddress.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.END);
```

[image: The better results show the "address" cutted without the ellipsize and the rest is "displayed" in another line.]

Starting with this xml, what can I do?

```
<com.neopixl.pixlui.components.textview.TextView
    android:id="@+id/wifispot_info_address"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="@string/default_string"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    pixlui:typeface="NeutraText-Book.otf"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:singleLine="true"/>
```

Comment: Add this `android:maxLines="1"`  . (`android:lines="1"`)Let me inform

Answer (score 0):

You can add `android:maxLines="1"`

> Makes the TextView be at most this many lines tall. When used on an
>   editable text, the inputType attribute's value must be combined with
>   the textMultiLine flag for the maxLines attribute to apply.

```
<com.neopixl.pixlui.components.textview.TextView
android:id="@+id/wifispot_info_address"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
android:layout_weight="0.5"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:text="@string/default_string"
android:textColor="@color/black"
android:textSize="16sp"
pixlui:typeface="NeutraText-Book.otf"
android:ellipsize="end"
android:scrollHorizontally="true"
android:singleLine="true"
android:maxLines="1"/>
```

Comment: This is the result using your code: [link](http://imgur.com/9Xjz7YA) Address get cutted by the middle of the word.

Comment: for test case remove `pixlui:typeface`

Comment: Same result (but with different font) :(

Comment: I "solved" it but using a different component. Never using `com.neopixl.pixlui.components.textview.TextView` anymore. :(

Comment: @JavierSivianes good .I assumed that your Custom class have problem